# How to compare telegram/mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, telegram

I send russian alphabet with inline-keyboard, in callback_data I pass the letter that user selected. It looks like this:

[image]

But telegram returns me this letter is this way `\xd0\xb3`.

I also save word for compare in mysql db. It returns in this way `\u0438\\u043c\\u043f\\u0435\\u0440\\u0430\\u0442\\u0438\\u0432`. The encoding in the database is `utf8_general_ci`.

And as a result, I need to check if the selected letter is in the word from the database. How can I do that?

Comment: 0xD0 0xB3 seems to be "CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER GHE" in UTF-8 encoding. Isn't that correct?

Comment: @Fildor when I select "CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER GHE" that u talk about I get "\xd0\xb3" from telegram

Comment: Please describe the exact problem. Getting the data as a character or as a byte sequence doesn’t matter. It’s the same thing as long as the data is read as UTF-8. So you’ll have to explain what part of your code doesn’t handle it correctly. There’s no code here to know what you’re doing, how you’re handling the database or anything else.

Comment: What you are storing into your database seems wrong to begin with. MySQL should be able to store these letters directly. You appear to have applied some sort of encoding function, or passed content to it without properly decoding it first. You should show more details of what you are actually doing (code), and proper examples of what data you receive to begin with.

Comment: Ah, now I see your problem ... \\uXXXX is a unicode code point. \u0400 is 0xD0 0x80. So \u0438 would be D0 B8 ... basically you need to "translate" between bytes and codepoints.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL never generates `\u0438`, a Unicode representation.  It will generate the 2-byte character whose hex is `D0B3` (which might show as `\xd0\xb3`), specifically a Cyrillic character.  And you *should* provide that format when `INSERTing` into a MySQL table.

PHP's `json_encode` will generate the Unicode form instead of the other, depending on the absence or presence of `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` in the second argument.

To check the database, do something like:

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) ...
```

If "correct" you should get something like

```
г  D0B3
```

(That's a Cyrillic GHE, not a latin `r`.)

Who knows what `telegram` is doing to the data.  There are over a hundred packages that use MySQL under the covers; I don't know anything about this one.

Terminology:  The *encoding* is `utf8` (or could be `utf8mb4`).  The *collation*, according to what you say, is `utf8_general_ci`.  Encoding is relevant to the querstion; collation has to do with the ordering of strings in comparisons and sorting.

Anoter example: Cyrillic small letter I `и` = utf8 hex `D0B8` = Unicode codepoint `\U0438`

HTML is quite happy with Unicode codepoints; it will show `и` when given `\U0438`.  Perhaps Telegram is converting to codepoints as it builds the web page?